# Changing the default position of new desktop items

Tags: xfce, desktop, xubuntu

In Xubuntu and most other similar environments newly created files, folders and shortcuts on desktop appear below each other, filling the desktop space one column at a time from top to bottom and left to right. Is it possible to change this behavior so that instead of columns the new items fill one row at a time, first item appearing in the top left corner and the second one on the right side of it and so forth?